# Whats the difference between JSP implicit object and EL expression implicit object?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have started reading JSP. I came across JSP implicit object, say for example, `session`, `application` etc. And after reading EL expression, i came to know there are also implicit object for EL expression.

My question is what is the difference between these implicit objects?

Even though they are semantically the same, why does they create EL and makes thing's little bit hard?

Correct me if am wrong

Comment: sorry for not adding these tags;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any difference in the object that you're getting, it's just different ways of accessing the same objects in each of the technologies. For example, `request` in a JSP will give you the same object as `${pageContext.request}` in EL.

In the case of EL, additional implicit objects are available for convenience, such as `param` or `requestScope`. You could still get the same data, but the syntax would be clumsy.

You might wish to compare this to implicit objects in a JSP vs. a 'lack' of implicit objects in Servlets. JSP implicit objects are not different from the objects that you can get a hold of in a Servlet, it's just that the implicit objects make for cleaner syntax. For example, the implicit `session` object is the same that you would get via `HttpServletRequest#getSession()`. An exception to this is the `pageContext` which has no equivalent in Servlets.

Comment: Yup thats what i have doubt; even though both produce the same, then why can't they didn't add these methods in the JSP implicit object itself, rather than sticking to EL?

Comment: Well, as I see it, one factor would be the syntax - IIRC, there is no straightforward way to invoke functions in EL. That makes it hard to make use of existing functions that aren't getters plus would make for awkward syntax.

Comment: Additionally, JSP implicit objects are meant to be used in scriptlets while the EL equivalents are meant to be used in EL expressions and are hence 'optimized' for that syntax.

Comment: The first couple of paragraphs of [this post](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/622/how-to-call-methods-from-el-expressions-pre-jsp-20-trick-for-jsps-with-jstl) might help clarify how EL works and what the shortcomings are.